# Prevent program from getting terminated after exception handling

Tags: java, exception

Is there anyway to handle the exceptions in Java and prevent the program from getting terminated? For instance when the user enters an invalid number into a calculator, zero in this example for division in the denominator, I don't want the program to get terminated and show the handled exception message. I want the program to continue and ask for another input.
Could anyone clarify it with a practical example for me?

Comment: Try to search "try-catch-finally" or "Exception handling" in google.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/

Comment: [here is your "example"](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/). Honestly go through the java basics, it might help you when creating even a tiny caluclator application.

Comment: @VimalBera I have read about that. But the problem is the program gets terminated and the finally block which executes code anyway won't help to cleanly manage the flow of the program for the next input

Comment: @FreeMind `try { calculate(); } catch (Exception e) { showErrorMessage(); }`

Comment: You need to write code that does this. Either with a try-catch statement or an if-elseif statement which will let. Even a while loop would work so that it keeps running till the while loop conditions are not satisfied anymore

Comment: @assylias If an exception is occured the program terminates in your example I want to avoid that.

Comment: @FreeMind honestly, go through the exceptions tutoral, it wont terminate. The program terminating there means, either other code is causing this, which also has to be corrected, or you´re not applying it correctly.

Comment: @KevinEsche Could you at least reference a complete tutorial on Java Exception handling instead of links to websites which explain this topic in general?

Comment: @FreeMind this is a complete tutorial, and judging the previous comment and the question itself, a general topic explenation wouldn´t do any harm either.

Comment: @KevinEsche I have read Java Exception Handling in general. I need some more clarification on the details.

Answer (score 1):

Simple: put a **loop** around the *whole* try catch block; like:

```
boolean loop = true;
while (loop) {
  try {
    fetch input
    loop = false;
  } catch (SomeException se) {
    print some message
  }
```

does the job in general.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
boolean exceptionOccured;

do {
    try {
        exceptionOccured = false;
        // code to read input and perform mathematical calculation
        // eg: a = 10/0;
    } catch(Exception e) {
        exceptionOccured = true;
        System.out.pritnln("Invalid input! Please try again");
    } finally {
        // some code that has to be executed for sure
    }
} while(exceptionOccured);
```

First the code inside the try block will be executed. When an execption occurs (like division by zero), execution of code jumps from try block to catch block where you can write your logic to loop the try-catch block.